# facebook fql order by random alternative in graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

```
$ret = $facebook->api( array(
'method' => 'fql.query',
'query' => "SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user = 1 ORDER BY rand() limit 12"
));
```

I was using this code for getting 12 random friend.But when I am replacing the above code with the below

```
$ret = $facebookObj->getFacebookRequestResponse($facebook, "GET", "/me/friends/?fields=id,name,picture&limit=12");
```

I am getting 12 friends but they are not coming in random order.How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no way to apply a custom ordering parameter to Graph API requests afaik.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#reading

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this will be to just retrieve all friends and assign them to an array, use a PHP random function to pull X randoms from the array

Such as

```
<?php
$input = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
echo $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
echo $input[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php